# How to validate a Number field in Javascript using Regular Expressions?

Tags: javascript

Is the following correct?

```
var z1=^[0-9]*\d$;
{
    if(!z1.test(enrol))
    {
        alert('Please provide a valid Enrollment Number');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Its not currently working on my system.

Comment: Close, a RegExp literal is enclosed in forward slashes: `/^[0-9]*\d$/`. You could also use `/^\d+$/`. Note that if the test passes, it just means its all digits, it isn't necessarily a valid enrolment number.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can test it as:

```
/^\d*$/.test(value)
```

Where:

1. The `/` at both ends mark the start and end of the regex
2. The `^` and `$` at the ends is to check the full string than for partial matches
3. `\d*` looks for multiple occurrences of number charcters

You do not need to check for both `\d` as well as `[0-9]` as they both do the same - i.e. match numbers.

Comment: Does not handle floats

Comment: `/^\d*$/.test('');` it fails for empty string

Answer (score 16):

```
var numberRegex = /^\s*[+-]?(\d+|\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*)([Ee][+-]?\d+)?\s*$/
var isNumber = function(s) {
    return numberRegex.test(s);
};

"0"           => true
"3."          => true
".1"          => true
" 0.1 "       => true
" -90e3   "   => true
"2e10"        => true
" 6e-1"       => true
"53.5e93"     => true

"abc"         => false
"1 a"         => false
" 1e"         => false
"e3"          => false
" 99e2.5 "    => false
" --6 "       => false
"-+3"         => false
"95a54e53"    => false
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks. Was tearing my hair out trying to find a just such a solution. Can also use just `^\s*[+-]?(\d+|\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*)?\s*$` if you don't require the scientific notation support.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var z1 = /^[0-9]*$/;
if (!z1.test(enrol)) { }
```

Remember, `*` is "0 or more", so it will allow for a blank value, too.  If you want to require a number, change the `*` to `+` which means "1 or more"

Answer (score 3):

You this one and it allows one dot and number can have "positive" and "negative" symbols

`/^[+-]?(?=.)(?:\d+,)*\d*(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value)`

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for something simple to test if a string is numeric, just valid numbers no +, - or dots.

This works:

> /^\d*$/.test("2412341")

*true*

> /^\d*$/.test("2412341")

*false*

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this regular expression for number validation

```
/^\\/(\d+)$/
```