# use replace to remove chars not existing in a regex match

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I'am trying to allow following pattern for a single html input box with javascript regex

- -int (aka any minus number so long it not followed by a zero and is in the first position)
- 0 (a single zero is allowed)
- int (is allowed)

I use this function the remove anything that doesn't match it

```
    $('.dointcheck').live('keyup',
        function () {
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace((/^((?!:([1-9-]?[0-9])).)/g), ''));
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(this).val(0);
            }
        });
```

which doesn't work.
Other examples is:

1. **/[^-0-9]/g** it removes any non valid chars but doesnt check if the minus is the beginning and is followed by a zero. It allows minus everywhere in the string
2. **(/^((?!:([1-9-]?[0-9])).)/g** Don't allow none.
3. **[^1-9-]?[^0-9]*** Allow all...

I think I'am missing something.. Any suggestions would be most appreciated..

Comment: [`.live()`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated with v1.7 and removed in v1.9

Comment: `<input type="number" ... />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this regex

```
^(0).*|^(-?)([1-9]\d*)?.*|^.*
```

and replace it with `$1$2$3` after input

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', ({ target }) => target.value = target.value.replace(/^(0).*|^(-)?([1-9]\d*)?.*|^.*/g, '$1$2$3'));
```

```html
<input />
```

It has three tests:

```
^(0).*               // if it starts with 0, discard everything after it
^(-)?([1-9]\d*)?.*   // otherwise it can only starts with a -, or any number that is not a 0. Then followed by other digits, then discard everything after it
^.*                  // if previous rules are not matched, discard everything
```

In short:

- generally only `-`, `0-9` are allowed.
- if you type a `0` first, nothing will be allowed after.
- if you type a `1-9` first, only numbers are allowed after.
- if you type a `-` first, only `1-9` is allowed next, then any digit is allowed after.

Comment: This is was I needed and the explanation what everything does is extremly helpfull

Answer (score 1):

I changed your regexp and made it a bit more modular and it worked fine.

```js
function toValidNumber(int) {
  return (/^\s*[+-]?(\d+|\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*)([Ee][+-]?\d+)?\s*$/).test(int) ? int : 0;
}

$('.dointcheck').live('keyup',
  function () {
    $(this).val(toValidNumber($(this).val()));
  });
```

[Orginal RegEXP in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57342060/18680620)